# What are the pros and cons to using AWS/S3 for static content?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want some little guidance from you all. I have a multimedia based site which is hosted on a traditional Linux based, LAMP hosting. As the site has maximum of Images /Video content,there are around 30000+ posts and database size is around 20-25MB but the file system usage is of 10GB and Bandwidth of around 800-900 GB ( of allowed 1 TB ) is getting utilized every month.

Now,after a little brainstorming and seeing my alternatives here and there, I have come up with two options

1. Increase / Get a bigger hosting plan.
2. Get my static content stored on Amazon S3.

While the first plan will be a simple option, I am actually looking forward for the second one, i.e. storing my static content on Amazon S3. The website i have is totally custom-coded and based on PHP+MySQL. I went through this http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/ and it gave me a fair idea.

I would love to know pros/cons when I consider hosting static content on s3.

Please give your inputs.

Comment: That's a fair old bit of traffic! However what you "should" do is rather a matter of opinion, and is quite general in nature. Stack Overflow is geared towards specific, answerable questions that would be of use to a future audience.

Comment: @halfer, I updated the question, I want to host my static content on s3, kindly let me know the pros/cons/howto based on your experience

Answer (score 3):

> Increase / Get a bigger hosting plan.

I would not do that. The reason is, storage is cheap, while the other components of a "bigger hosting plan" will cost you dearly without providing an immediate benefit (more memory is expensive if you don't need it)

> Get my static content stored on Amazon S3.

This is the way to go. S3 is very inexpensive, it is a no-brainer. Having said that, since we are talking video here, I would recommend a third option:

[3.] Store video on AWS S3 and serve through CloudFront. It is still rather inexpensive by comparison, given the spectacular bandwidth and global distribution. CloudFront is Amazon's CDN for blazing fast speeds to any location.

If you want to save on bandwidth, you may also consider using Amazon Elastic Transcoder for high-quality compression (to minimize your bandwidth usage).

Traditional hosting is way too expensive for this.

Answer (score 1):

### Bigger Hosting Plan

going for a bigger hosting plan is not a permanent solution because

1. As the static content images/videos always grow in size. this time your need is 1 TB the next time it will increase more. So, you will be again in the same situation.
2. With the growth of users and static content your bandwidth will also increase and will cost you more.
3. Your database size is not so big and We can assume you are not using a lot of CPU power and memory. So you will only be using more disk space and paying for larger CPU and memory which you are not using.
4. Technically it is not good to server all your requests from a single server. Browser has a limited simultaneous requests per domain.

### S3/ Cloud storage for static content

s3 or other cloud storage is good option for static contents. following are the benefits.

1. You don't need to worry about the storage space it auto scales and available in abundance.
2. If your site is accessible in different location worldwide you can manage a cdn to improve the speed of content delivered from the nearest location.
3. The bandwidth is very cheap as compared to the traditional hosting.
4. It will also decrease burden from your server by uploading your files and serving from s3.

These are some of the benefits for using s3 over traditional hosting. As s3 is specifically built to server the static contents. Decision is yours :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the long term, at some point you might not be able to afford a server that will hold all of your data. I think S3 is a good option for a case like yours for the following reasons:

1. You don't need to worry about large file uploads tying down your server. With [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html), you can upload files directly from the client to your S3 bucket.
2. Modern browsers will often load parallel requests when a webpage requests content from different domains. If you have your pictures coming from yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com and the rest of your website loading from yourdomain.com, your users might experience a shorter load time since these requests will be run in parallel.
3. At some point, you might want to use a Content Distribution Network (CDN) to serve your media. When this happens, you could use Amazon's cloudfront with out of the box support for S3, or you can use another CDN - most popular CDNs these days do support serving content from S3 buckets.
4. It's a problem you'll never have to worry about. Amazon takes care of redundancy, availability, backups, failovers, etc. That's a big load off your shoulders leaving you with other things to take care of knowing your media is being stored in a way that's scalable and future-proof (at least the foreseeable future).